# Serial/Ethernet Gadget Raspberry pi zero

Tags: usb, pi-zero, gadget, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye

I'm trying this 'ethernet mode' on raspberry pi zero with **bullseye** and bonjour installed on windows 10 following this guide
[Ethernet Gadget](https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/ethernet-gadget) without success.

My main goal is to get control on network less environment

after editing `config.txt` with `dtoverlay=dwc2` and `cmdline.txt` with `modules-load=dwc2,g_ether` after rootwait.

I get to this point where the raspberry pi appears in the device manager as a COM, but no RNDIS in network adapters.

and I cant use putty to connect it

this is the point I'm stuck on, I've add also ssh file to boot and I can **ssh** into the pi via local network

[image: NO RNDIS]

This is the message that I'm getting from putty when trying to serial connect with baud 115200

[image: PUTTY ERROR]

Does anyone manage to connect the pi in gadget mode and can assist me?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a link to the tutorial you used...

Comment: @Dirk fixed it now

Comment: how did you fix it? serial baud 9600?

Comment: @A.J.Bauer just fixed the link for Dirk, but please let me know if there is any new progress.

Comment: I have the same issue with a RPi Zero 2 W. I'm using the exact same configuration as on my RPi Zero W, which is working. The only differences are A: Zero 2 W vs Zero W, B: Raspbian Bullseye vs Buster.

Comment: Update: I swapped the memory cards and the problem followed with the card. RPi Zero 2 W works fine with Raspbian Buster. From what I know now I would conclude that this is a problem with Bullseye.

Answer (score 1):

This is likely an issue of missing RNDIS drivers.

I worked through the same issue today, I was seeing it with both the latest Bullseye (2021-10-30) and and the current legacy Buster (2021-12-02) image of Raspberry Pi OS.

[This thread](https://forums.raspberrypi.com/viewtopic.php?t=245184#p1955773) helped me out, after installing the `USB Ethernet/RNDIS Gadget` from the optional drivers in Windows Update my Raspberry Pi was correctly identified as an network device.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is Windows 10 unable to detect the USB Ethernet gadget.
You need to install the drivers through a windows update or by a google search.